# How to combine two event listeners on different elements and close existing active when other is clicked?

Tags: javascript, toggle, addeventlistener

I have two separate event listeners in a header for cart and hamburger menu. How do i merge both event listeners and place a condition such that if the other is clicked while the existing is active, it will close the existing and allow the other to be active?

I tried a while and if condition but it did not work.

```
const navlinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const navtoggle = document.querySelector(".nav-toggle");

navtoggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navlinks.classList.toggle("active");
});

const cartopen = document.querySelector(".cartopen");
const cartside = document.querySelector(".cart-sidebar");

cartopen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cartside.classList.toggle("active");
});



while (navlinks.className === "active") {
  if (cartside.className === "active") {
    navlinks.classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to bundle the event listeners and the elements, just hide an element on the document's click. Write a class to handle a popup behavior and attach to each element independently